# mvn command line java compiler version is mistaken

Tags: java, maven

I have jdk8 and 9 installed. And in the effective pom.xml I can see the compiler plugin is assigned to 1.8, however mvn clean install prints error a sun class is missing, making me believe it still uses jdk9.

```
$ mvn -version
Maven home: D:\Java\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
```

pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Java 9 can compile Java 8. It's not mistaken. That java is in your PATH variable

Comment: @cricket_007 then why bother configuring maven-compiler-plugin source and target 1.8

Comment: Because you would run the compiled code on a system that has no Java 9 support

Comment: @cricket_007 have jdk9 installed for months, and it is the first time the project uses a mistaken jdk version.

Comment: @cricket_007 I finally got this work again! After rebooting os. Sure maven compiler plugin could use another jdk version, as its official doc says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an edge case.

You (presumably) have some code that was originally developed for Java 8 (or earlier) that depends on an internal JRE class.  Code is **not supposed to do that**.

What has apparently happened is that the internal class has been removed or replaced.

The only way you are going to be able to compile this code is by downloading and installing a genuine Java 8 JDK and setting your `$PATH` to refer to it before running Maven.

But that is only a stop-gap.  The real solution is to convert your code so that id doesn't depend on internal classes.  You are going to have to do that eventually anyway.  So may as well do it now ... and avoid the hassle of a special Java 8 setup to build your code.

---

There is nothing you can do with your POM file to fix this.  Those classes are (probably) no longer present in the "rt.jar" file where the java compiler and runtime are looking for them.

---

> I finally got this work again! After rebooting os.

What probably happened is that you changed a PATH setting in a ".rc" file but did not restart your shell or re-source the file.  Or something like that.  The reboot probably wasn't necessary.  Logging out and logging in again would probably have been sufficient.

Comment: usually people have jdk8 installed, and use source and target as 1.7 and it works. now people have jdk9 installed, and source and target as 1.8 and it causes a problem?

Comment: using jdk 9 for now is not a good idea, since maven does not support it and so many jar files from repository have issues too.

Comment: I'm sure that Maven itself does support Java 9.  Those issues with 3rd-party JARs will progressively be resolved as the libraries are recompiled / ported.  The problems with sun classes etc are actually the fault of the 3rd-party libraries: 1) they should have avoided using those internal classes in the first place, 2) Java 9 and the hiding / removal of internal classes has been in the pipeline for a long time.  The maintainers should have prepared for it.

Comment: after more tests, I think you are right, maven-compiler-plugin uses the `java --version` jdk to compile and check some(?) compatibility for its `source` configuration, if API exists in `java --version`  but not in that source version, it continues, but if compatibility fails (like lambda), it breaks. Just no idea what are these "some compatibility"